# C Program keeps changing int after I add a loop

Tags: c, loops, integer, cs50

I am fairly new to C so I must be doing something wrong. I have an `int` that keeps changing because of a loop, doesn't matter what kind of loop it is, it just changes the code to give me a completely different number due to the loop

What I am expecting (which is what I get before I add the loop):

```
first_set = 200001208
```

Once I add the loop:

```
first_set = 0
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong since for test purposes my loop should not affect the current code at all.

Here is the current code

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

string verify_card(long n);
int get_length(long n);
long get_reversed(long n);
int luhnsI(int l);

int length;
long poo;
int r_array[20];
int index = 0;

int main(void)
{
    long num;
    do
    {
        num = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while (num < 1000000000);
    verify_card(num);
}

string verify_card(long n)
{
    printf("%li\n", n);
    length = get_length(n);
    get_reversed(n);
    int first_set = luhnsI(length);
    int first_set_length = get_length(first_set);

    //Test loop, if you remove this loop. It will change the int to something else
    //for (int yt = 0; yt < first_set_length; yt++)
    //{
    //    printf("test");
    //}

    printf("%i\n", first_set);

    return 0;
}

int get_length(long n)
{
    int l = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}

long get_reversed(long n)
{
    while (n != 0)
    {
        //Copy the n into the array
        r_array[index] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int luhnsI(int l)
{
    int number;
    char string[l];
    char results[l];
    int total = 0;

    //Get every other num starting from second to last
    for (int x = 1; x < l; x = x + 2)
    {
        number = r_array[x] * 2;
        sprintf(string, "%d", number);
        strcat(results, string);
    }
    int results_num = atoi(results);
    //Add the total of all the numbers together

    return results_num;
}
```

Comment: Don't pass length to luhnsI.  Just have a large enough string for any number + null terminator.  Right now, it is too short.

Comment: Do nlt use a single letter variable `l` (lower-L).  In many fonts it is easily confused with `1` (one).

Comment: You have used a data type `string` - presumably from cs50.h and declared a `char` array of the same name.  That is a bad idea.  You have a number of  global variables - always an bad idea and never necessary.

Comment: `index` as a global is just incorrect.  If you call `get_reversed` more than once, it will fail.

Comment: Choose a better function name that `luhnsI` too.  What is the purpose of this code.  It seem rather more complex than necessary and as a consequence fixing it is more difficult than necessary.  It is not clear from the comments, because you talk about numbers when I think you mean digits and and "adding" when I think you mean concatenation.  You should probably do this arithmetically rather then with string handling.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple instances of exceeding array bounds, the result of which is undefined, but never good.  Exceeding the bounds of an array generally means stomping on the memory occupied by something else.  Such as the stack space of the calling function or adjacent variables.  Often an array bounds error has no obvious immediate impact, but the code will change behaviour in unexpected ways when it is changed - ins this case such as adding the loop - or more likely possibly the call in the loop

For example `get_length()` returns the number of digits in the input, which you then use to create variable length arrays (VLAs) in `luhnsI()`, however you did not account for the nul terminator of the strings. It is probably not necessary to use VLA, a 32-bit positive integer will be no more than 10 digits, and 64-bit 20 digits.

Additionally you `strcat()` `string` to `result` but `result` is too short and will not grow, and is uninitialised - you have no way of telling what it contains and exactly where the initial data will be concatenated.

VLAs are best avoided, as is `strcat()`, but all string and array handling  should be performed with far more care.

Answer (score 0):

A few dos and donts for you to study:

- don't use global variables
- don't use `l` as a variable name as it looks confusingly close to `1`
- do allocate extra space for the null byte terminator at the end of C strings
- don't use `sprintf`, always prefer `snprintf`
- don't use `strcat` with an uninitialized destination array
- don't use `strcat` without a careful analysis of the destination maximum length.
- don't use numbers to represent card numbers that may have leading zeroes or too many digits
- don't use a complicated method where a simple one would be used to solve the problem by hand

Here is a simplified solution using numbers:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int verify_card(long n);

int main(void) {
    long num;

    do {
        num = get_long("Number: ");
    } while (num < 1000000000);

    return verify_card(num);
}

int verify_card(long num) {
    int sum = 0;

    // Compute the Luhn sum: handle 2 digits at a time
    for (long n = num; n > 0; n = n / 100) {
        int digit0 = n % 10;
        int digit1 = (n / 10 % 10);
        digit1 = digit1 * 2;
        if (digit1 > 9) {
            digit1 = digit1 - 10 + 1;
        }
        sum = sum + digit0 + digit1;
    }
    if (sum % 10 == 0) {
        printf("%ld is valid\n", num);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("%ld is invalid, Luhn sum is %d\n", num, sum);
        return 1;
    }
}
```